# Meteor run a function after database connection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to read from the database and aggregate some results, and then set a number of reactive variables on the client. I can only do this after the database has been connected.

I tried to do it in `onRendered`,

```
Template.header.onRendered(function(){
    recalculate();
});
```

It works locally, but not when deployed to `meteor.com`. Where should I do the function call?

Comment: You should use waitOn subscriptions in iron-router

Comment: I'm not using iron-router...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onRendered` callback has nothing to do whatsoever with data over the wire, it simply tells you when the template appears on the DOM (unless you archaically wait for the data to start rendering).

It works locally because the data is very fast to arrive and can be ready before a template rendering (which takes a few milliseconds).
However on real conditions latency appears: the data takes a while to arrive.
Since you use an inappropriate way to know how your data is ready, stuff goes wrong. It would have failed just as badly if you had used any other kind of arbitrary trigger:

```
setTimeout(recalculate, 150);
```

To know when the database has connected, use the [subscription's built-in ready callbacks](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

```
var dataSub = Meteor.subscribe('my data', recalculate); //Method 1
Tracker.autorun(function(computation) {
  if(dataSub.ready()) {
    computation.stop();
    recalculate();
  }
}); //Method 2
```

Choose one of the two methods.
The second one is more modular since you can have multiple computations watching one subscription.

Comment: Thank you, a problem is that I am using the autopublish package... Perhaps I have to remove it and use subscriptions?

Comment: @user1506145 You'd better, yes. `autopublish` is intended to be used for simple quick & dirty prototyping (like, creating the skeleton of an app in a day or two). It should generally not be used in applications facing the web.

Comment: Yes, but I am using it in a personal app just for own use

Comment: @user1506145 Having `autopublish` also makes it harder to tell whether or not data have arrived, which is what you want to achieve.